# Combining entire column of Arrays into one Array

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have this dataframe and I'd like to combine all the arrays,
in the data column, into one big array, separate from the DataFrame.

Scala and DataFrame API are still pretty new to me, but I gave it a shot:

```
case class Tile(data: Array[Int])

val ta = Tile(Array(1,2))
val tb = Tile(Array(3,4))
val tc = Tile(Array(5,6))

df =  ListBuffer(ta,tb,tc).toDF()

// Combine contents of DF into one array
val result = new Array[Int](6)
var offset = 0
val combine = (t: WrappedArray[Int]) => {
    Array.copy(t, 0, result, offset, t.length)
    offset += t.length
}

df.foreach(r => combine(r(0).asInstanceOf[WrappedArray[Int]]))

df.show()
+------+
|  data|
+------+
|[1, 1]|
|[2, 2]|
|[3, 3]|
+------+
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
16/08/23 11:21:32 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 17.0 (TID 17)
scala.MatchError: WrappedArray(1, 1) (of class scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef)
at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.array_apply(ScalaRunTime.scala:71)
at scala.Array$.slowcopy(Array.scala:81)
at scala.Array$.copy(Array.scala:107)
at $line150.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:32)
at $line150.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:31)
at $line190.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:46)
at $line190.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:46)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$32.apply(RDD.scala:912)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$32.apply(RDD.scala:912)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1869)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1869)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:74
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: There are so many things that are wrong with this code. your use of `offset` inside the function makes it so that it will not be `Serializable`. Also your `combine` is defined to take 2 parameters but you are providing it 1.

Comment: You're right, that second argument shouldn't be there. I just fixed it. Scala language and using DataFrames are new to me, so I'm still figuring out the Spark/Scala way of doing things. @SarveshKumarSingh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with Spark you can not accumulate things using a foreach like you do normally. Since spark distributes the work among all executors, your `function` needs to be `Serializable`.

In case you still want to do things in a way similar to what you normally do, then use `Accumulator` which supports spark's distributed model.

```
val myRdd: RDD[List[Int]] = sc.parallelize(List(List(1,2), List(3,4), List(5,6))

val acc = sc.collectionAccumulator[Int]("MyAccumulator")

myRdd.foreach(l => l.foreach(i => acc.add(i)))
```

Or in your case

```
case class Tile(data: Array[Int])

val myRdd: RDD[Tile] = sc.parallelize(List(
  Tile(Array(1,2)),
  Tile(Array(3,4)),
  Tile(Array(5,6))
))

val acc = sc.collectionAccumulator[Int]("MyAccumulator")

myRdd.foreach(t => t.data.foreach(i => acc.add(i)))
```

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback! You made a good point about the function needing to be serializable.   I should've known better. I forgot to mention that I'm running Spark 1.6. I couldn't find anything regarding collectionAccumulator for that version. However, I ended up converting the DataFrame Column into an RDD, collecting, and aggregating the arrays. I was wondering if there was a more direct route, as opposed to converting to an RDD. In the mean time, I'll keep playing around with it.